# db class function not recognised

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Getting an:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method UsersController::select() application/models/User.php on line 27

It looks like the UsersController is not sending the select function to the db.class.php which I have inside a library folder.

The db.class.php is being loaded however not in this case.

code inside the UserController.php class is:

```
class User extends Model
{        

/**
 * Login method
 *
 * @todo: update last_login_time
 * @todo: add hashing
 */
public function user_login() {

    $username = $_POST['data']['User']['username'];
    $password = $_POST['data']['User']['password'];


    $bind = array(
        ":username" => $username,
    );
    $result = $this->select("users", "username = :username", $bind);

    //Check the password returned from the db against the password entered
    if (Bcrypt::checkPassword($password, $result[0]['password']) == true) {
        Session::init();

        Session::set('user_logged_in', true);
        Session::set('user_id', $result[0]['id']);
        Session::set('user_name', $result[0]['username']);
        Session::set('user_permission', $result[0]['permission']);
        Session::set('user_role', $result[0]['role']);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


/**
 * Log out process, deletes cookie, deletes session
 *
 * @todo implement rememberme cookie
 */
public function logout()
{
    // set the remember-me-cookie to ten years ago (3600sec * 365 days * 10).
    // that's obviously the best practice to kill a cookie via php
    // @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/686166/1114320
    //setcookie('rememberme', false, time() - (3600 * 3650), '/', COOKIE_DOMAIN);

    Session::init();
    // delete the session
    Session::destroy();
}

}
```

Select Function inside db.class.php

```
public function select($table, $where="", $bind="", $fields="*") {
    $sql = "SELECT " . $fields . " FROM " . $table;
    if(!empty($where))
        $sql .= " WHERE " . $where;
    $sql .= ";";
    return $this->run($sql, $bind);
}
```

I think it maybe the reference to $this->select() but I'm learning.

Comment: If you are posting about a specific error you **must** include the full error message (with line number) and at least the code on that line and the line before it.

Comment: What this error tells me is that the class UserController does not have a method called select(). Is that Laravel?

Comment: And where is the `select()` method?

Comment: @N.DeNisse - It's cake php.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is `select()`, from what I can tell, is not a method of `User`, `Model`, or some other parent in the hierarchy of `Model`.

Instead it is in db.class.php.

Given the current code, I suggest injecting a *DB* object into `User`/`Model` and then delegate to this object directly.

For example:

```
class Model {
    public function __construct(DB $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

Then, to resolve the error, in `User` do:

```
$result = $this->db->select("users", "username = :username", $bind);
```

**Note:** This is incomplete. So you'll need to fill in a few blanks. Since you are learning, I suggest reading:

- [Object Inheritance in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php)
- [Dependency Injection in PHP](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dependency-injection-in-php--net-28146)
- [What is the purpose of a delegation pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168714/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-delegation-pattern)

Also, *.class.php* is an old naming convention used in PHP 4. Do not do this. Instead, follow the [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) naming convention.

Comment: Ok - will give this a try, I may need to hit the books again ha ha

Comment: Saw your updated comment, if this is supposed to be CakePHP, this code does not follow their convention.

Comment: Thanks - I'm struggling to understand it, but learning all the same.