# Effective Java item 16 (2nd edition) - Is Forwarding class only used to allow re-use?

Tags: java, oop, effective-java

I am going through `Effective Java, Item-16 Favor composition over inheritance`. I looked at the `Forwarding class` example below.

I am wondering what's the point of having a `ForwardingSet` class? `InstrumentedSet` can very well implement `Set` and have a private instance of it which invokes all the methods.

Is it to promote re-use and prevent redundancy if we end up having more `InstrumentedSet` like classes in the future which just need to do something in addition to the base behavior? Is it just future-proofing the design or is there something else to it that I am missing?

```
// Reusable forwarding class 
public class ForwardingSet<E> implements Set<E> {     
  private final Set<E> s;     
  public ForwardingSet(Set<E> s) { this.s = s; }     
  public void clear()               { s.clear();            }    
  public boolean contains(Object o) { return s.contains(o); }
...
}

// Wrapper class - uses composition in place of inheritance   
public class InstrumentedSet<E> extends ForwardingSet<E> {     
      private int addCount = 0;     
      public InstrumentedSet(Set<E> s) { super(s); } 
      @Override public boolean add(E e) {         
          addCount++;
          return super.add(e);
       }
       ...
    }
```

Comment: Note, this refers to Effective Java 2nd edition. In 3rd edition, the item number for "Favor composition over inheritance" is changed to 18.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes, `ForwardingSet` is a framework.

If you have to write several `Set`s that work with other `Set`s internally but provide different functionalities on top of the "vanilla" `Set`, you'd better write the common part once and not several times.

Joshua Bloch, in *Effective Java* refers to it as "composition", though the actual implementation looks more like the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

An actual implementation is readily available in [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), as a class named [`ForwardingSet`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingSet.html).

> Is it to promote re-use and prevent redundancy if we end up having more InstrumentedSet like classes in the future which just need to do something in addition to the base behavior?

Yes.

> Is it just future-proofing the design?

Yes.

> or is there something else to it that I am missing?

No, you're not missing anything.

Comment: My next question is: Do we do this every time we think there might be a need to `decorate` the API with more than the default behavior? Like say APIs which on the face of it aren't screaming the need for re-use. Let's say retrieving and returning some items from the database.

Comment: @linuxNoob No. Not every time, start thinking about refactoring into a `Forwarding...` class only when several wrappers are written.

Comment: @linuxNoob If the object being decorated implements a lot of methods, and you're only modifying the behavior of a few (if any), then having a delegate-only base class helps separate the delegation logic from the decoration logic, i.e. the base class only does delegation, so it doesn't really need to be tested and reviewed, and the subclass only does the decoration, so it needs to be tested and reviewed. The decoration logic will not "drown" in a sea of delegation logic. See also: [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Answer (score 4):

*Is it to promote re-use and prevent redundancy?* Yes.
*Is it just future-proofing the design?* Yes.
*Is there something else to it that I am missing?* No.

The "forwarding" is commonly referred to as "**delegation**".
See: [What is the purpose of a delegation pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7168714/5221149)

Some examples of Java classes with delegate-only implementations:

- [`java.io.FilterInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) (and [`java.io.FilterOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html), [`java.io.FilterReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilterReader.html), [`java.io.FilterWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilterWriter.html))

  > The class `FilterInputStream` itself simply overrides all methods of `InputStream` with versions that pass all requests to the contained input stream. Subclasses of `FilterInputStream` may further override some of these methods and may also provide additional methods and fields.
- [`javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestWrapper.html) (and [`javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponseWrapper.html), [`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html), [`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html))

  > Provides a convenient implementation of the `ServletRequest` interface that can be subclassed by developers wishing to adapt the request to a Servlet. This class implements the **Wrapper** or **Decorator** pattern. Methods default to calling through to the wrapped request object.