# Add Target to UITextField within a UITableview (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I want to check when the user starts editing a text field.  There is a great clear answer on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394933/how-do-i-check-when-a-uitextfield-changes).

However, in my case my textField is within a UITableview that's set up as its own class.  I've tried lots of different ways to get this to work, but I keep getting the crash "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"  I put a break in the textFieldDidChange func and it never gets called so the problem seems to be with how I'm calling that func from the target.

```
class TextFieldCell: UITableViewCell {

    lazy var textField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tf.textAlignment = .center
        tf.textColor = .black
        tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
        tf.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
        return tf
    }()

    // For simplicity, the rest of the Cell setup not shown.
    // Adds target in AirInput VC to fire method when editing happens

    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AirInputViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)

}


class AirInputViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

    }

}
```

I also tried the following for the target and it crashes as well.

```
textField.addTarget(AirInputViewController.self, action: #selector(AirInputViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
```

It feels like I'm missing something simple, but I have no idea what that simple fix is.  Or perhaps should I add the target in the AirInputViewContoller?  If so, how would I access the UITableViewCells where the Text Field is?  Thanks!

Comment: Usually there is a pointer to what caused the exception before "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.". Would you mind posting the whole crash?

Comment: Do you mean this? "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: No, usually the output is waaaay longer. I have a hunch of what can be happening. Posted an answer. If it's not the case, I can just delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your crash is due to the fact that you do:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AirInputViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
```

Here `self` is `TextFieldCell`, so I think it tries to go and check that `AirInputViewController` is inside `TextFieldCell`, which is not the case.

I would do:

```
class TextFieldCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate: TextFieldCellDelegate?

    lazy var textField: UITextField = {
        // same you have
    }()

    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)

    @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        delegate?.textFieldDidChange(textField)
    }
```

Create a fancy delegate:

```
protocol TextFieldCellDelegate: class {
     func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField)
}

class AirInputViewController: TextFieldCellDelegate {

    func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // textField just changed!
    }

    // IMPORTANT! Set the delegate for the cell!

    func tableView(...cellForRow...) {
        let cell = ... as! TextFieldCell
        cell.delegate = self
        ...
        return cell
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think I see where you are going, but can't quite get it to work.  What is the purpose of the protocol?  I get the error "objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes" when implementing it.

Comment: I am sorry, the protocol and its `textFieldDidChange` should have not been `@objc`. The purpose of the protocol is to create a delegate. The events inside the cell are then handled *within the cell* and one uses the `delegate` to inform the controller about the events the controller needs to know about, nothing else. Basically the event observer for a view should be inside that view, not in a different class.

Comment: I appreciate the help.  Now without the @objc it gives the error "Protocol methods must not have bodies".

Comment: It means that I made the mistake of declaring the method inside the protocol as `func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {}`, meaning it had a body. Modified it to be only `func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField)`

Comment: That did the trick!  Thanks so much for working through that with me and teaching me something new.  Now I just need to stare at it for a while to internalize what's going on better.  :)

Comment: The Delegate Pattern is very useful and spread in Swift, so I advise you to get familiar with it. Here some examples and explanations for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168714/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-delegation-pattern. The protocol here inherits from `class` so the variable can be `weak` and that way avoid a retention cycle because the controller has the view and the view would have a reference of the controller as the delegate. So by making the delegate weak, the view does not have a strong reference to the controller and there is no cycle.